# Exception while writing to MifareUltralight

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, nfc, mifare

I get an exception while trying to write a MifareUltralight NFC tag on Android. The error shown in logcat is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void    android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference at   
    .MainActivity.getTagInfo(MainActivity.java:124) 
    com.mynfctest.MainActivity.resolveIntent(MainActivity.java:106)
    com.mynfctest.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:98)
```

How I can solve this error?

Write method:

```
public static boolean writeOnMifareUltralight(Context _context, Tag tag, String pageData, int i) {
    MifareUltralight mifare = null;

    int size=pageData.length();
    try {
        mifare = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
        mifare.connect();
        mifare.writePage(i, pageData.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("skm", ex.getMessage());
        // return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            mifare.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Write method called from my activity:

```
switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
        boolean result=NFCHammer.writeOnMifareUltralight(this,tag,tvName.getText().toString(),4);

        if(result){
            findViewById(R.id.incProgressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent Callintent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
            Callintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(Callintent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
        else{
            findViewById(R.id.incProgressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            CommonTask.createToast("Tap The card again!!!", this, Color.RED);
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: I got  wirte exception mifare.writePage(i, pageData.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));     boolean result=NFCHammer.writeOnMifareUltralight(this,tag,tvName.getText().toString(),4);

Comment: logcat error--  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference at .MainActivity.getTagInfo(MainActivity.java:124)
           com.mynfctest.MainActivity.resolveIntent(MainActivity.java:106)
            .com.mynfctest.MainActivity.onNewIntent(MainActivity.java:98)

Comment: Edit your post, don't comment your logcat here.

Comment: thanks, why any body unvote my question. I want to know that .please help

Comment: It seems your error in logcat has nothing to do with nfc. You have an error in class MainActivity line 124, you call setVisibility on a null object

Answer (score 0):

As the exception explains, you are calling the method `setVisibility` on a `null` ob ject reference:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '... setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

In other words, somewhere in your code, you have a like this:

```
object.setVisibility(...);
```

and on this like the variable `object` is `null` and does not reference a real object.

The stacktrace of the exception further tells you that the exception occured on line 124 of the file MainActivity.java, more specifically inside a method named `getTagInfo`:

> at .MainActivity.getTagInfo(MainActivity.java:124)

As you did not reveal enough code to verify if the problem comes from those code snippets that you posted, we can only speculate that the problem comes from the two lines that set the visibility of a view `R.id.incProgressBar` to `GONE`:

```
findViewById(R.id.incProgressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If that's the case, then `findViewById(R.id.incProgressBar)` returned `null`, indicating that the view `R.id.incProgressBar` was not found in the current view hiearchy of the activity.